# Ajax call not posting data to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm having a html list with integer value data, and i would like to post these integers to the controller. Nonetheless, the jquery code actually does NOTHING, not even error message appeared. The button that calls the jquery is in a modal box. Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#additem-dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function () {
                var proList = document.getElementsByClassName("proItem").value;
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SetTempList","Admin")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(proList),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success!');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
                $("#search-form").submit();
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#opener").on("click", function () {
        $("#additem-dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

and here is the controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SetTempList(List<int> proList)
    {
        TempData["detailList"] = proList.ToList();
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong, I tried other kinds of data to test the ajax call, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Define "does nothing".  Does the JavaScript code execute at all?  When you debug it in your browser, what does it do?  Is there an error on the browser's debugging console?  Is the AJAX call made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is that data?  What is the server's response?  "Does nothing" doesn't really provide much information.  If nothing is invoking this code in the first place then clearly the problem is outside of this code.

Comment: the only thing I know that this ajax call return null value...

Comment: Well, the return type for the server-side method is `void`.  So I wouldn't expect it to return a value.  `void` literally means "this method doesn't return anything".  What exactly are you *expecting* to happen and what *does* happen?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, the URL you're trying to POST to is just a string, or is it replaced by the framework you're using?

A good way to check if the POST is sent to the correct URL is to enable the developer console (**F12** in most browsers) and check the networking tab after pressing "Add".

Comment: well I have found the problem that the proList is not readable, thanks anyway :D